# Image or Div behind Div (HTML web development)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before I start explaining my problem, I want to make it clear on what I am working on. I am making a site where you are in an "elevator". When you press on any of the 6 buttons of the elevator, the door opens and information appears on the blank space. But when I actually try to put anything inside the blank space, the div "rightdoor" and "leftdoor" shift down and the information I am trying to put stays `ontop...`

My question is, how to prevent div from going doing? 
And how to put div behind another div?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes leftdooropen {
  from {
    right: 0%;
  }

  to {
    right: 50%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rightdooropen {
  from {
    left: 50%;
  }

  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes leftdoorclose {
  from {
    right: 50%;
  }

  to {
    right: 0%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rightdoorclose {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }

  to {
    left: 50%;
  }
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#leftdoor {
  background-image: url("Door.png");
  position: relative;
    /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#rightdoor {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url("Door.png");
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.lframe {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rframe {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.myButton {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#celevator {
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
}

#1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css">

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="leftdoor">
        <img class="lframe" src="frame.png">
    </div>

    <div id="1">

    </div>
    <div id="rightdoor">

        <img class="rframe" src="frame.png">

        <button class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:80%; bottom:75%;" onclick="openelevator(this)">1</button>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:71.9%; bottom:68%;" onclick="openelevator(this)">2</a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:63.8%; bottom:61%;" onclick="openelevator(this)">3</a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:55.9%; bottom:54%;" onclick="openelevator(this)">4</a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:48%; bottom:47%;" onclick="openelevator(this)">5</a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:38%; bottom:35%;" onclick="openelevator(this)">Earth</a>
        <a href="#" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:25%; bottom:27%;" onclick="openelevator(this)">> | <</a>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: add your js code also

Comment: to put div on div use z-index: [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your first question "how to prevent div from going doing?".
If you can provide a properly working example we can get a clear idea.

However to your second question "how to put div behind another div?", did you mean something like this?

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #eee;
}
.div-1, .div-2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #6e6ebf;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
.div-2{
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background: #6ebfad;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-1">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="div-2">
    Div 2
  </div>
</div>
```